# Как делать выбор города с названием города в урл Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет!

Подскажите как реализовать название города в url?

Есть модалка со списком городов, у каждого города есть slug. Как после клика на город, сделать чтобы slug города был всегда после названия домена, пока не выбрали другой?

Список городов храниться в базе

Answer (score 0):

Вообще хорошей практикой считается подставлять город (либо другое значение влияющее глобально на выдаваемый контент) в виде поддомена, например ufa.domain.ru (Взять хотя бы пример со Stackoverflow - ru.stackoverflow.com) и ставить Wildcard сертификат.

```
Route::domain('{account}.domain.ru')->group(function () {
    Route::get('someurl/{id}', function ($data, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

Но если отвечать именно как поставлено в вопросе, то:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
```

Хорошего кодинга!

Comment: Это понятно, но как сделать проверку на существование города в адресной строке с городами в таблице? Если такого города например не существует то редирект на главную, а если город равно городу по умолчанию, то убирать из строки?

Comment: Да это делается банальными Middleware, почитайте https://laravel.su/docs/8.x/middleware

Comment: И получается при каждом переходе по урл мы будем стучатся к таблице городов с проверерй?

Comment: Иначе никак - это точно! единственное, что можно предпринять - это закэшировать информацию о городах, поскольку эта информация довольно статична.